# Check all audio sample rates supported by android device

Tags: java, android, audio

I want find out which sampling rates are supported by each device. I did this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    frequencyslist = menu.addSubMenu("frecuencias de muestreo");
    int idx = 0;
    int[] list = { 8000, 11025, 16000, 22050, 44100, 96000, 1000000 };
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(list[i],
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_DEFAULT,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
        if (bufferSize != -2) {

            frequencyslist.add(2, idx, Menu.NONE, String.valueOf(list[i]));
            idx++;
        }

    }

    return true;
}
```

But all rates that I try are present in the menu, rather than just the supported ones.

Comment: I'd at least check for any error condition, not just -2, and perhaps for sake of curiousity log the actual returned buffer sizes.  It is a little surprising all of those are supported, but consider trying some really ridiculous numbers and see if you can get a rejection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Chris said in his comment, you should be checking for *any* error condition, not just `-2`. [The docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html#getMinBufferSize%28int,%20int,%20int%29) say that it can return `ERROR_BAD_VALUE` **or** `ERROR`. If it is returning `ERROR` (-1), then you're still adding that value to the list.

As for *why* it's returning that:

> ...or ERROR if the implementation was unable to query the hardware for its input properties...

You may not be able to query it or some reason. Maybe it's blocked by another operation, maybe you don't have permission, etc. I'm not sure if you need `android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO` to simply query it, but check that you have it in your manifest.

Side note: `CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_DEFAULT` was deprecated a long time ago. You should be using `CHANNEL_IN_DEFAULT`.

Comment: I check the logcat and buffersize returns {640,640,1280,640,7680,7680,7680} to my frecuencies.It´s extrange. Do you know other way to doing this comprobation?